# VBA Vlookup is too fast to account for changing variables

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a tool, that will help me decide which contractor to use for a construction project, based on some set criteria. Each contractor has been promised a set % of the total households built in a given quarter.

I have set up a bunch of SUMIFS functions in Excel, that generate a list of the next 25 quarters, and suggests a contractor based on their current % of the total (such that the contractor that is currently furthest from getting the promised % is suggested), the dataset is pulled from a server that is updated once a day.

My original plan was to enter data for project#1, extract the quarter from the date, and then use Vlookup to return the suggested contractor for that quarter based on my list of 25 quarters.

This works fine without any VBA-code, but now I've run into an issue I can't solve.

As the dataset is only updated once a day, when a contractor is suggested for project#1, the number of households need to be added to their total for the quarter, such that it is accounted for when suggesting a contractor for project#2. But since the suggested Contractor is based on their current total, it creates a circular reference.

I tried instead to do the Vlookups with VBA, as i hoped VBA would run the code such that:

```
Vlookup performed for project#1 - Suggests Contractor A

Total values change, suggested contractor changes

Vlookup performed for project#2 - Suggests Contractor B
```

However, when i run the Macro, it looks like it runs all 30 Vlookups simultaneously, such that the change in totals is not accounted for until the end.
Is there a way to make it do what i want? Either by delaying each Vlookup until Excel has had time to calculate the new totals, or by other means that I don't have the capacity to think up?

I have posted my code and some screenshots below, and as you can see, I have absolutely no clue about VBA, so all I have done is to input 30 Vlookups in a row. I am certain that this could have be done much, much more elegantly, but sadly I have no clue how.

```
    Sub test()
 'pn Equals Postnumber (Zipcode)
 'Entr Equals Suggested Contractor
 'Lookup1-30 equals the lookup value for each project (the quarter)
 'myrange equals the lookup-list where i have calculated suggested contractor for all quarters
 
Dim pn1 As Long
Dim pn2 As Long
Dim pn3 As Long
Dim pn4 As Long
Dim pn5 As Long
Dim pn6 As Long
Dim pn7 As Long
Dim pn8 As Long
Dim pn9 As Long
Dim pn10 As Long
Dim pn11 As Long
Dim pn12 As Long
Dim pn13 As Long
Dim pn14 As Long
Dim pn15 As Long
Dim pn16 As Long
Dim pn17 As Long
Dim pn18 As Long
Dim pn19 As Long
Dim pn20 As Long
Dim pn21 As Long
Dim pn22 As Long
Dim pn23 As Long
Dim pn24 As Long
Dim pn25 As Long
Dim pn26 As Long
Dim pn27 As Long
Dim pn28 As Long
Dim pn29 As Long
Dim pn30 As Long

Dim Entr1 As String
Dim Entr2 As String
Dim Entr3 As String
Dim Entr4 As String
Dim Entr5 As String
Dim Entr6 As String
Dim Entr7 As String
Dim Entr8 As String
Dim Entr9 As String
Dim Entr10 As String
Dim Entr11 As String
Dim Entr12 As String
Dim Entr13 As String
Dim Entr14 As String
Dim Entr15 As String
Dim Entr16 As String
Dim Entr17 As String
Dim Entr18 As String
Dim Entr19 As String
Dim Entr20 As String
Dim Entr21 As String
Dim Entr22 As String
Dim Entr23 As String
Dim Entr24 As String
Dim Entr25 As String
Dim Entr26 As String
Dim Entr27 As String
Dim Entr28 As String
Dim Entr29 As String
Dim Entr30 As String

pn1 = Sheets("Input").Range("C3").Value
pn2 = Sheets("Input").Range("C4").Value
pn3 = Sheets("Input").Range("C5").Value
pn4 = Sheets("Input").Range("C6").Value
pn5 = Sheets("Input").Range("C7").Value
pn6 = Sheets("Input").Range("C8").Value
pn7 = Sheets("Input").Range("C9").Value
pn8 = Sheets("Input").Range("C10").Value
pn9 = Sheets("Input").Range("C11").Value
pn10 = Sheets("Input").Range("C12").Value
pn11 = Sheets("Input").Range("C13").Value
pn12 = Sheets("Input").Range("C14").Value
pn13 = Sheets("Input").Range("C15").Value
pn14 = Sheets("Input").Range("C16").Value
pn15 = Sheets("Input").Range("C17").Value
pn16 = Sheets("Input").Range("C18").Value
pn17 = Sheets("Input").Range("C19").Value
pn18 = Sheets("Input").Range("C20").Value
pn19 = Sheets("Input").Range("C21").Value
pn20 = Sheets("Input").Range("C22").Value
pn21 = Sheets("Input").Range("C23").Value
pn21 = Sheets("Input").Range("C24").Value
pn22 = Sheets("Input").Range("C25").Value
pn23 = Sheets("Input").Range("C26").Value
pn24 = Sheets("Input").Range("C27").Value
pn25 = Sheets("Input").Range("C28").Value
pn26 = Sheets("Input").Range("C29").Value
pn27 = Sheets("Input").Range("C30").Value
pn28 = Sheets("Input").Range("C31").Value
pn29 = Sheets("Input").Range("C32").Value
pn30 = Sheets("Input").Range("C33").Value

lookup1 = Sheets("Target").Range("R8").Value
lookup2 = Sheets("Target").Range("R9").Value
lookup3 = Sheets("Target").Range("R10").Value
lookup4 = Sheets("Target").Range("R11").Value
lookup5 = Sheets("Target").Range("R12").Value
lookup6 = Sheets("Target").Range("R13").Value
lookup7 = Sheets("Target").Range("R14").Value
lookup8 = Sheets("Target").Range("R15").Value
lookup9 = Sheets("Target").Range("R16").Value
lookup10 = Sheets("Target").Range("R17").Value
lookup11 = Sheets("Target").Range("R18").Value
lookup12 = Sheets("Target").Range("R19").Value
lookup13 = Sheets("Target").Range("R20").Value
lookup14 = Sheets("Target").Range("R21").Value
lookup15 = Sheets("Target").Range("R22").Value
lookup16 = Sheets("Target").Range("R23").Value
lookup17 = Sheets("Target").Range("R24").Value
lookup18 = Sheets("Target").Range("R25").Value
lookup19 = Sheets("Target").Range("R26").Value
lookup20 = Sheets("Target").Range("R27").Value
lookup21 = Sheets("Target").Range("R28").Value
lookup22 = Sheets("Target").Range("R29").Value
lookup23 = Sheets("Target").Range("R30").Value
lookup24 = Sheets("Target").Range("R31").Value
lookup25 = Sheets("Target").Range("R32").Value
lookup26 = Sheets("Target").Range("R33").Value
lookup27 = Sheets("Target").Range("R34").Value
lookup28 = Sheets("Target").Range("R35").Value
lookup29 = Sheets("Target").Range("R36").Value
lookup30 = Sheets("Target").Range("R37").Value

Set myrange = Sheets("Target").Range("M8:O35")

If pn1 > 999 And pn1 < 5000 Then Entr1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup1, myrange, 2, False)
If pn1 > 4999 And pn1 < 10000 Then Entr1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup1, myrange, 3, False)
If pn2 > 999 And pn2 < 5000 Then Entr2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup2, myrange, 2, False)
If pn2 > 4999 And pn2 < 10000 Then Entr2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup2, myrange, 3, False)
If pn3 > 999 And pn3 < 5000 Then Entr3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup3, myrange, 2, False)
If pn3 > 4999 And pn3 < 10000 Then Entr3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup3, myrange, 3, False)
If pn4 > 999 And pn4 < 5000 Then Entr4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup4, myrange, 2, False)
If pn4 > 4999 And pn4 < 10000 Then Entr4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup4, myrange, 3, False)
If pn5 > 999 And pn5 < 5000 Then Entr5 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup5, myrange, 2, False)
If pn5 > 4999 And pn5 < 10000 Then Entr5 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup5, myrange, 3, False)
If pn6 > 999 And pn6 < 5000 Then Entr6 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup6, myrange, 2, False)
If pn6 > 4999 And pn6 < 10000 Then Entr6 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup6, myrange, 3, False)
If pn7 > 999 And pn7 < 5000 Then Entr7 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup7, myrange, 2, False)
If pn7 > 4999 And pn7 < 10000 Then Entr7 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup7, myrange, 3, False)
If pn8 > 999 And pn8 < 5000 Then Entr8 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup8, myrange, 2, False)
If pn8 > 4999 And pn8 < 10000 Then Entr8 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup8, myrange, 3, False)
If pn9 > 999 And pn9 < 5000 Then Entr9 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup9, myrange, 2, False)
If pn9 > 4999 And pn9 < 10000 Then Entr9 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup9, myrange, 3, False)
If pn10 > 999 And pn10 < 5000 Then Entr10 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup10, myrange, 2, False)
If pn10 > 4999 And pn10 < 10000 Then Entr10 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup10, myrange, 3, False)
If pn11 > 999 And pn11 < 5000 Then Entr11 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup11, myrange, 2, False)
If pn11 > 4999 And pn11 < 10000 Then Entr11 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup11, myrange, 3, False)
If pn12 > 999 And pn12 < 5000 Then Entr12 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup12, myrange, 2, False)
If pn12 > 4999 And pn12 < 10000 Then Entr12 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup12, myrange, 3, False)
If pn13 > 999 And pn13 < 5000 Then Entr13 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup13, myrange, 2, False)
If pn13 > 4999 And pn13 < 10000 Then Entr13 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup13, myrange, 3, False)
If pn14 > 999 And pn14 < 5000 Then Entr14 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup14, myrange, 2, False)
If pn14 > 4999 And pn14 < 10000 Then Entr14 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup14, myrange, 3, False)
If pn15 > 999 And pn15 < 5000 Then Entr15 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup15, myrange, 2, False)
If pn15 > 4999 And pn15 < 10000 Then Entr15 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup15, myrange, 3, False)
If pn16 > 999 And pn16 < 5000 Then Entr16 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup16, myrange, 2, False)
If pn16 > 4999 And pn16 < 10000 Then Entr16 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup16, myrange, 3, False)
If pn17 > 999 And pn17 < 5000 Then Entr17 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup17, myrange, 2, False)
If pn17 > 4999 And pn17 < 10000 Then Entr17 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup17, myrange, 3, False)
If pn18 > 999 And pn18 < 5000 Then Entr18 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup18, myrange, 2, False)
If pn18 > 4999 And pn18 < 10000 Then Entr18 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup18, myrange, 3, False)
If pn19 > 999 And pn19 < 5000 Then Entr19 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup19, myrange, 2, False)
If pn19 > 4999 And pn19 < 10000 Then Entr19 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup19, myrange, 3, False)
If pn20 > 999 And pn20 < 5000 Then Entr20 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup20, myrange, 2, False)
If pn20 > 4999 And pn20 < 10000 Then Entr20 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup20, myrange, 3, False)
If pn21 > 999 And pn21 < 5000 Then Entr21 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup21, myrange, 2, False)
If pn21 > 4999 And pn21 < 10000 Then Entr21 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup21, myrange, 3, False)
If pn22 > 999 And pn22 < 5000 Then Entr22 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup22, myrange, 2, False)
If pn22 > 4999 And pn22 < 10000 Then Entr22 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup22, myrange, 3, False)
If pn23 > 999 And pn23 < 5000 Then Entr23 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup23, myrange, 2, False)
If pn23 > 4999 And pn23 < 10000 Then Entr23 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup23, myrange, 3, False)
If pn24 > 999 And pn24 < 5000 Then Entr24 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup24, myrange, 2, False)
If pn24 > 4999 And pn24 < 10000 Then Entr24 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup24, myrange, 3, False)
If pn25 > 999 And pn25 < 5000 Then Entr25 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup25, myrange, 2, False)
If pn25 > 4999 And pn25 < 10000 Then Entr25 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup25, myrange, 3, False)
If pn26 > 999 And pn26 < 5000 Then Entr26 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup126, myrange, 2, False)
If pn26 > 4999 And pn26 < 10000 Then Entr26 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup26, myrange, 3, False)
If pn27 > 999 And pn27 < 5000 Then Entr27 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup27, myrange, 2, False)
If pn27 > 4999 And pn27 < 10000 Then Entr27 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup27, myrange, 3, False)
If pn28 > 999 And pn28 < 5000 Then Entr28 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup28, myrange, 2, False)
If pn28 > 4999 And pn28 < 10000 Then Entr28 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup28, myrange, 3, False)
If pn29 > 999 And pn29 < 5000 Then Entr29 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup29, myrange, 2, False)
If pn29 > 4999 And pn29 < 10000 Then Entr29 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup29, myrange, 3, False)
If pn30 > 999 And pn30 < 5000 Then Entr30 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup30, myrange, 2, False)
If pn30 > 4999 And pn30 < 10000 Then Entr30 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup30, myrange, 3, False)

Sheets("Input").Range("G3").Value = Entr1
Sheets("Input").Range("G4").Value = Entr2
Sheets("Input").Range("G5").Value = Entr3
Sheets("Input").Range("G6").Value = Entr4
Sheets("Input").Range("G7").Value = Entr5
Sheets("Input").Range("G8").Value = Entr6
Sheets("Input").Range("G9").Value = Entr7
Sheets("Input").Range("G10").Value = Entr8
Sheets("Input").Range("G11").Value = Entr9
Sheets("Input").Range("G12").Value = Entr10
Sheets("Input").Range("G13").Value = Entr11
Sheets("Input").Range("G14").Value = Entr12
Sheets("Input").Range("G15").Value = Entr13
Sheets("Input").Range("G16").Value = Entr14
Sheets("Input").Range("G17").Value = Entr15
Sheets("Input").Range("G18").Value = Entr16
Sheets("Input").Range("G19").Value = Entr17
Sheets("Input").Range("G20").Value = Entr18
Sheets("Input").Range("G21").Value = Entr19
Sheets("Input").Range("G22").Value = Entr20
Sheets("Input").Range("G23").Value = Entr21
Sheets("Input").Range("G24").Value = Entr22
Sheets("Input").Range("G25").Value = Entr23
Sheets("Input").Range("G26").Value = Entr24
Sheets("Input").Range("G27").Value = Entr25
Sheets("Input").Range("G28").Value = Entr26
Sheets("Input").Range("G29").Value = Entr27
Sheets("Input").Range("G30").Value = Entr28
Sheets("Input").Range("G31").Value = Entr29
Sheets("Input").Range("G32").Value = Entr30

End Sub
```

[Input Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyVtC.png)
[Data analysis Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RosF.png)

Comment: You should probably research using Variant arrays.  It will greatly simplify your code and make it run even quicker.

Comment: Thank you Scott, I'll look into it! I find my main issue with VBA as opposed to Excel, is that I don't know enough of the language to google my way to solutions.

Comment: If each vlookup is predicated on changes being made to the sheet before the next vlookup, you will need to loop the sheet and do each vlookup and then grab the data to put in the next vlookup.  As is you are grabbing all the data which then becomes static in the variables, and doing all the vlookups on that static data.  You will need to grab the data for the next vlookup after the previous vlookup runs.

Comment: @ScottCraner "You should probably research using Variant arrays" for this question is perhaps the understatement comment of the year.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I think i understand. And you gotta start somewhere @PGSystemTester :)

Comment: @Morten indeed. We've all been there. `Arrays` are slightly more complex than loops/if statements/variables but they simplify EXACTLY what you're trying to do with all those duplicated variables. Unfortunately VBA isn't the easiest starter langauge for arrays due to the 2 dimensional nature. Good luck.

Comment: @PGSystemTester from what I can gather, rewriting the code such that it loops through an array will greatly simplify the code. But won't I still have the issue Scott describes, that VBA treats my data as static when I run the code? Or can I get the data, run the first lookup in my array, and then retrieve the same data again?

Comment: Honestly, I didn't even look at your code beyond the massive need for arrays. However, Scott's usually correct.

Comment: @Scott Craner outside of rewriting the code to loop through an array, do you have any pointers as to how I can re-grab my data after each lookup? I'll be sure to rewrite it as soon as I've learnt how, but it would be a shame to have the code all neat if it still doesn't do the job

Comment: An array will not work here as you stated it would be just as static as the approach you are using.  You will need to use dynamic referencing to grab the data after each vlookup is run to use in the next vlookup.

Comment: @Scott Craner thanks, I'll look into it!